# If $|C\times C|=|\mathbb{R}|$, then can we conclude that $|C|=|\mathbb{R}|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm curious, is there a simple argument to suggest that if a set $C$ satisfies $|C\times C| = |\mathbb{R}|$, that $|C| = |\mathbb{R}|$ as well? It seems trivially true, but I'm having trouble coming up with a simple argument for it. Obviously, if $|C| = |\mathbb{N}|$ then $|C\times C| = |\mathbb{N}|\neq |\mathbb{R}|$, and if $|C| > |\mathbb{R}|$, then $|C\times C|\ge |C|>|\mathbb{R}|$. This might *seem* like a proof, but it only works under the continuum hypothesis, since it assumes there is no set $X$ with $|\mathbb{N}| < |X| < |\mathbb{R}|$.

It's obvious that if $C\times C$ is *uncountable*, then $C$ must be uncountable, since the contrapositive, that $C$ being countable implies $C\times C$ is countable, in this case makes no assumption of the *exact* cardinality of $C\times C$. Without the continuum hypothesis, how do we know there isn't an "uncountable" set $X$, with $|X|<|\mathbb{R}|$ and $|X\times X|=|\mathbb{R}|$?

**Edit:** Additionally, is this possible without the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: Isn't it true for any infinite set $S$, continuum hypothesis or no, that the cardinality of $S\times S$ is the same as that of $S$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's a good point, I'll play around with that idea.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_multiplication

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hmm, the only thing I'm not quite satisfied with is that it relies on AoC. For what I'm trying to do I don't think that's a big deal, but I would be curious to see if there's a way to do it without.

Comment: No need to bring politics into it...

Comment: AC is [necessary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice#Equivalents) here.

Comment: [Tarski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_theorem_about_choice)

Comment: I’m pretty sure you need AC, since it is consistent with ZF without Choice that the real numbers are a countable union of countable sets. Not quite $C\times C$, but pretty close.

Comment: Note that the axiom of choice is needed to assign cardinalities to arbitrary sets (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @Sambo: The axiom of choice is needed to represent cardinalities as _initial ordinals_. If you don't have AC you can still speak of _cardinalities_, but you need to represent them as sets in a different way, such as by Scott's Trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $C$ was finite, then $C\times C$ would also be finite, and its cardinal would be strictly lower than that of the set of real numbers. On the other hand, if $C$ is infinite, then $C\times C\approx C$ (this is a consequence of Hessenberg's theorem - in some of the literature -, toghether with **AC**; c.f. 4.26 in https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mapdw/current-set-theory.pdf. Notice that this statement is dependent of the Axiom of Choice; one can easily prove this fact using the axiom under the form of **Zorn's Lemma** [it would be an interesting exercise for you to try to prove this, if you are familiar with this kind of topics]). By transitivity, if $|C\times C|=2^{\aleph_0}$, then $C$ is an infinite set, and also $|C|=2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't depend on AoC? I would have thought that transfinite induction would only work if you know your cardinal $C$ can be given an ordinal structure (i.e. a well-ordering.)

Comment: You are mistaken about Hessenberg’s Theorem. Hessenberg’s Theorem is that for an infinite **cardinal** $\kappa$, you have $\kappa\times\kappa \approx \kappa$. This is not the same as saying that for every infinite set $C$ you have $C\times C\approx C$, because that claim requires that the set $C$ be bijectable with a cardinal in order to apply Hessenberg’s Theorem, and the claim that every infinite set is bijectable with a cardinal is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice. In fact, the claim that $C\times C\approx C$ for all infinite sets is equivalent to Choice.

Comment: (Your edit still misses the point, that it is not the same to make a statement about cardinals as to make a statement about cardinalities; cardinals “come” with a well-ordering, so there is a lot of stuff you can do without having to invoke Choice that you cannot do for arbitrary sets)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, ah I see. I forgot that a cardinal is defined to also be an ordinal. So yes, the issue is whether $C$ can be given a cardinal structure.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip: It’s not you, it’s the original poster, who is misquoting Hessenberg’s Theorem. The latter is about cardinals, but Akerbeltz is claiming it is about arbitrary sets; if you state it for arbitrary sets, then it is *not* Hessenberg’s Theorem, and that statement is equivalent to AC, by a theorem of Tarski.

Comment: @Akerbeltz: No, Hessenberg’s theorem does not depend on the Axiom of Choice, because it is about cardinals, which are special kinds of ordinals, which are well ordered.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You are totally right, completelly missed that point. Thanks for the comments.